# How to i enable child child gameobject component in unity5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi i have some gameobjects my hierarchy:
I have attached screenshot once look into that.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9THXI.png)

from that image how to disable meshcollider component for plane.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: GameObject.Find("Plane").SetActive(true);

Comment: transform.Find("Camera").Find("Plane").gameObject.SetActive(true);

Comment: **(1)** Look through every object in your game and find the one called "Plane" and activate the gameobject.

**(2)** from the scripts gameObjects transform, find a child called "Camera", and from that find a child called "Plane" and set that gameobject to active. _Setting a gameobject to active or not active will remove it without destroying it, so you can toggle it back and forth._

Answer (score 1):

If you have only **one** specific component that you want disable (and this component only exists once in your hierarchy of children), you can use `GetComponentInChildren<Component>().enabled = false`.